# Conteúdo de <p> vindo do banco ultrapassa limite da div

Tags: php

Fiz um site em PHP em que a maioria dos conteúdos vêm do banco de dados.
Em uma das páginas, o conteúdo esta ultrapassando os limites da div e se sobrepondo a outro conteúdo.

Ja olhei o CSS e os limites estão ok.

Segue foto [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o código que está dentro de um col-6

```
<h4>Potências</h4>
<p><?php echo $potencia; ?></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como os dados estão todos juntos (sem espaços) é possível que ele entenda tudo como uma unica palavra, então coloque a seguinte linha no seu css dessa tag `<p>`:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, funcionou!